# Numpy install wants to create tmp file in lib folder where I do not have write access

Tags: python, bash, numpy, filesystems, setuptools

I want to install numpy for python3 on a local file system with a Hadoop cluster so that I can use the library in pyspark. The problem is that I cannot install numpy without it failing at a step where it attempts to make a tmp file in the python3 subfolder, except it's trying to create said tmp file to the write-restricted lib, and every workaround I have tried has continually failed at this point. Screenshot with exact error:

[PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib64/python3.6'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6I2k.png)

I have tried to point my .bashrc file to the directory with the python3 installation and the other packages I have installed for my own use in addition to what is currently in the write-protected lib file on the local filesystem. .bashrc below. What more do I have to do so that this step in the numpy install creates the tmp file in the python3 package that I have write-access to?

[current .bashrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr5Fe.png)

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/ Text, please! Copy/paste from the terminal. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of options:- ( I would select the virtual environment one because it's the cleanest solution that worked for me easily without tampering anything else.)

1. One being using `sudo` to get the root access and install it there.
2. Other options are - install it in a separate virtual environment. (or maybe install it in user folder).

Answer credit: [Github issue link](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/236#issuecomment-383039470)

Comment: Choosing option 2 in the above answer is recommended as it keeps the system python clean.

Comment: @akazuko That's what I said. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install with the pip of python3.6 of the system, not with the python that you have in your `/run/user` path. Using your current `python` alias, try to install numpy with

```
python -m pip install numpySOMETHING.whl
```

To prevent conflicts, please consider use environments with `virtualenv` or `conda`.

If you only have the TMP issue, you can solved it creating a temporary folder in your current directory.

```
if [[ -O $PWD/TMP && -d $PWD/TMP ]]; then
    TMPDIR=$PWD/TMP
else
    rm -rf $PWD/TMP 2> /dev/null
    mkdir -p $PWD/TMP
    TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d $PWD/TMP/XXXX)
fi

TMP=$TMPDIR
TEMP=$TMPDIR
export TMPDIR TMP TEMP
```

And when you finish the installation.

```
unset TMPDIR TMP TEMP
```